# Google Classroom API suddenly returning quota errors

Tags: api, batch-processing, google-classroom

I have routines that synchronize Class/Roster information between an SIS and Google Classroom.  Everything has been running smoothly until very recently (11/1/2016).  Now we're seeing the following message in all of our log files for routines that handle Classroom syncs.

```
Insufficient tokens for quota group and limit 'DefaultGroupUSER-100s' of service 'classroom.googleapis.com', using the limit by ID...
```

We perform batch requests whenever possible and these errors are showing up in individual batch "part" responses.  The fact that these errors suddenly started showing up for ALL of our Classroom routines makes me think that something changed on the Google end of things.

I've been playing around with the throttling on our end by changing both the number of requests that we send in each batch ([docs](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/batch) say that you can send 1000 per batch) as well as the total number of requests/batches that we're sending per 100 seconds ([docs](https://developers.google.com/classroom/limits) say you can send 50/s/client and also 5/s/user).  Interestingly, the quotas indicated in the development console display slightly different but I assume they are to be interpreted in conjunction with one another.

[image: Google Developer Console - Classroom Quota]

I've throttled things down to the point where we're not even getting close to 5 requests per second and I'm still getting these errors back from the server.

Can someone provide some suggestions or solutions.  Has anyone experienced this lately?

Let me know if I any additional information is needed.

Comment: Try adding delays per request ([Exponential Backoff](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff) Java Sample). Here are some related issue that encountered the same error - [#970](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=970) and [#612](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=612) which was solved by increasing their quota. Also check your [API console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/enabled), to view the quotas and usage of the API, request and error ratio. (which I think you are already doing).

Comment: Lastly you can try and report a [bug](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?labels=Type-Defect,API-Classroom), based from your question that it previously run with any error. Hope this helps.